# What's wrong with this string checking program?

Tags: c

I want to make this program only English in the string, but when the end of the string ends in English, another strange word is added. Why is that?

```
int main(void) 
{

    char line[100];
    char line2[100];    

    printf("Please enter a string: ");
    gets_s(line, sizeof(line));

    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        while(line[i] >= 'A'&& line[i] <= 'z') {
            line2 [k++] = line[i++];
        }
    }
    line2[k] = '\0';
    printf("string: %s\n", line2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include sample input and output

Comment: The nested loop which also increments `i` will definitely cause issues, as the inner loop will also break on the null-terminator, causing the outer loop to read the next character after that

Comment: Unrelated: in ASCII, between `'A'` and `'z'` there are some characters that are not letters (like `'['` and `']'`).

Comment: I don't think you mean "only English".  Strings like "akthekci" and "gestalt" and "stovokor" match the condition you seem to be trying to code, but they are not English.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> for(int i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
>     while(line[i] >= 'A'&& line[i] <= 'z') {
>         line2 [k++] = line[i++];
>     }
> }
> ```

replacing the `for` loop with a `while` loop...

```
int i = 0;
while (line[i] != '\0') {
    while (line[i] >= 'A' && line[i] <= 'z') {
        line2 [k++] = line[i++];
    }
    i++;
}
```

So, here you can see if the inner `while` goes to the `'\0'` `i` gets incremented past the terminating zero byte.

Comment: When I turn it around in the visual studio, I still get weird text. Just type hello.

Comment: Hmm ... my answer is an explanation, not a fix :-)

Comment: This is the fix: `while (line[i]) { if (isalpha((unsigned char)line[i])) line2[k++] = line[i]; i++; }` ... remember to `#include <ctype.h>` for `isalpha()` prototype.

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that you put responsibility for incrementing `i` in two different places.  As a result, it can get incremented more than you want -- for example, so as to skip over the string terminator.

It appears to me that you have caused this problem for yourself by making the code more complicated than it needs to be.  Why use a two-loop nest to iterate over a single string?  In fairness, there are indeed potential reasons to do that, but none of them appear to be in evidence here.  I suggest changing the inner `while` loop to an `if` statement, and not incrementing `i` within:

```
    for (int i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (line[i] >= 'A' && line[i] <= 'z') {
            line2[k++] = line[i];
        }
    }
```

Note how there is only one place where `i` is incremented in that variation.

Note also that there may be characters that satisfy `c >= 'A' && c <= 'z'` but are not letters.  I say "may" because C is not specific to a particular character set or encoding, but in practice, it is virtually certain that there are non-letter characters in that range on your implementation.  Perhaps `isalpha((unsigned char) line[i])` would be a better fit, though it is not, by itself, without character set related issues.